# I am getting TypeError when trying to print a value loaded from a json file

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am getting TypeError when trying to print a value from a json file using python.

I am trying to retrieve one item from  the hobbies in the json file below

```
{"name": "Jason",
"hobbies": ["music", "programming", "games"],
"job": "Software Developer"}
```

Using the following code

```
import json
with open('input.json', 'r') as input:
    obj = json.load(input)
    print('Hello, ' + obj['hobbies'])
```

I am getting the following error, not sure how to retrieve from the list

> TypeError: can only concatenate str (not "list") to str

any help would be much appreciated

Comment: `obj['hobbies']` is a list which you are trying to concatenate to str. *"I am trying to retrieve one item from the hobbies"* is vague. What item?

Comment: Which hobbie are you looking for? Currently you are trying to concatenate music, programming, and games to the string which is not allowed. You need to index that object at a specific element to do that

Comment: Hi Austin I am trying to retrieve music

Comment: So `obj['hobbies'][0]`, then?

Comment: thank you very much for your help

Answer (score 2):

this will work:

```
import json
with open('input.json', 'r') as input:
    obj = json.load(input)
    #make it a string
    print('Hello, ' + str(obj['hobbies']))
```

what you need to do is make it a string.
that is what str does

this for one item:

```
import json
with open('input.json', 'r') as input:
    obj = json.load(input)
    #make it a string the item is the first one
    print('Hello, ' + str(obj['hobbies'][0]))
```

Comment: Cheers Matthijs990 that worked a treat, what is the code if I just want to show one of the hobbies please?

Comment: something like this will do the job

Answer (score 0):

An answer catered to the modified question according to the comments. You should change that:

```
import json
with open('input.json', 'r') as input:
    obj = json.load(input)
    print('Hello,', obj['hobbies'][0])
```

Using a comma will give you an automatic string conversion of the object to string, or as Matthijs990 said just convert the object to string first, however this is less pythonyc

```
print('Hello, ' + str(obj['hobbies'][0]))
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help

Comment: It's normal on this website to upvote solutions that help you and then mark one of them as the one that solved the problem as "accepted solution"